# How to Properly Catch a PHP error on Ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, exception, dojo, trace

I am retrieving javascript code from the server via the following ajax call

ajax (dojo):

```
dojo.xhrGet({
    url : 'script.php',
    handleAs : "javascript",
    load : function(response){
        /*Do Something*/
    },
    error : function(errorMessage) {
        console.error(errorMessage);
    }
});
```

script.php works fine, and, if the javascript code it returns is not valid code, the error handler will be invoked. However, the error message is incomplete, ie. it only shows the last function the error occurred in, not the entire chain of function calls. This is at times not very useful as I want to know where the error originated. Is there any way to output the entire trace?

Comment: What is the output of the script.php in case of an error?

Comment: marc, I figured out what the problem was, that is not the issue, but in case you want more insight, the actual error was `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < `. My guess is that b/c the code is now dynamically executed, Chrome is not listing all the function calls, just where the execution began (the ajax call).

Comment: So in case of failure, your php script answers with `SyntaxError: ...` and http code `200`?

Comment: Sorry, the `console.error(errorMessage)` line generates the following error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < script.js:198` where `script.js` is the name of the javascript file with the ajax call at line 198, and then the code itself generates a similar error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < dojo.xd.js:14` which I presume is where the implementation for the dojo ajax call is stored.

Comment: I would *guess* that since you have handleAs: "javascript", dojo is interpreting the response of your xhr request as javascript, and that response has an unexpected < in it.

Comment: Yes james, my question is if there is a way to better pinpoint where exactly that unexpected '<' is occurring. What if the code I am loading is 20,000+ lines?

Comment: What do the PHP script answers in case of an error? Could you do the call to the php script manually and give the output. Maybe the script fails and contains a php error. With your stacktrace it is very probable that the error is related to the script.

Comment: marc: it's not a PHP error, it's the javascript code that is executed on return that's invalid, that's the error. Lets say I fetch the following code as 'javascript' with PHP `var xyz = 'missing end quote;` It will claim there is an invalid string or what not. but what if instead I fetch `var xyz = A();` and `A()` returns `B()` which returns ...`Z()` and `Z()` returns the invalid string, I want a trace of all the functions, not just where the error arose.

Answer (score 0):

Post the response of what you are returning.

I think you are better trying with a JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error object on xhrPost for a _saveCustom, even though my response status was 200 (the 'handle:' is the same for GET and POST).

Actually handle: as 'json' will threw the error as well, but handle as 'text' worked and triggered the call to the load callback function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I wasn't getting reliable error information is because I was using `eval` and I was expecting the same behavior I would observe having instead included those scripts. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380204/is-there-a-performance-gain-in-including-script-tags-as-opposed-to-using-eval) describes the differences and how `eval` runs the code whereas including those codes first inserts the code into the DOM **then** runs the code. The former is more efficient, but the latter is easier to debug.